# i want to chop right side of the menu container using css code

Tags: html, css

please look at the image below i am trying to cut part of the menu container on the right side of it , it is plain and nothing is there and its not needed at the moment so how do i cut it down
[image]

this is the part i want to cut down on as it is useless and wasting space

i tried using

```
margin-top: 8px;
margin-bottom: 3px;
```

they dont work it only moves the text instead

here is what it has

```
width: 1170px;
background: #fff;
box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,.5) 0 3px 20px 0;
width: 1170px;
background: #fff;
box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,.5) 0 3px 20px 0;
font-family: Arial, serif;
```

changing the with moves the texts instead of container

Comment: Set the width ?

Comment: Have you given the white container that content has a set width?

Comment: You will need to post your code here in order for us to see what's going on.

Comment: Please provide enough code for us to replicate the problem. Preverable a snippet, use the <> button in the editor to add a self contained snippet. By reducing the problem to a smaller self contained example you may find the answer yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Using `margin-top` and `margin-bottom` will only change the margins directly above and below the container. Try setting a max-width property on your container:

```
#YourContainer {
  max-width: 1000px;  /*You may need to change this to suit your page*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i fixed it thanks guys

```
width: 1170px;
```